# Dynamic rendering of React components without using evil eval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I have a working solution (below) for dynamically loading my React components in scenarios where I can't load them explicitly, using data attributes in markup. I'm conscious of my use of 'eval' to get the dynamic component from the component registry and I'm looking for a better solution.

```
export default class DynamicComponentRenderer {

/**
 * Creates an instance of DynamicComponentRenderer.
 * 
 * @param {object} element The DOM element to make into a component.
 * 
 * @memberOf DynamicComponentRenderer
 */
constructor(element, componentRegistry) {
    Guard.throwIf(element, "element");
    Guard.throwIf(componentRegistry, "componentRegistry");

    this.element = element;
    this.componentName = element.getAttribute("data-react-component");
    this.DynamicComponent = eval(`componentRegistry.${this.componentName}`);
    this.props = {};

    if (!this.DynamicComponent) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to create a component of the name '${this.componentName}'.`)
    }

    Array.prototype.slice.call(element.attributes).filter((attrib) => 
        (attrib.name.includes('data-') && !attrib.name.includes('data-react-component'))
    ).forEach((attrib) => {
        this.props[attrib.name.replace(/data-/i, '').replace(/-[a-z]/, (match) => {
            return match.toUpperCase();
        }).replace(/-/, '')] = attrib.value;
    });
}

/**
 * Renders the dynamic React component.
 * 
 * @returns Rendered HTML.
 * 
 * @memberOf DynamicComponentRenderer
 */
render() {
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(this.DynamicComponent, this.props), this.element);
}
}
```

The componentRegistry that is passed in is from a component Index file that looks a bit like this...

```
export default {
    DataList: DataList,
    Form: {
        Buttons : {
             Submit: SubmitButton,
             Cancel: CancelButton
        }
    }
    OwnedAddress: OwnedAddress
}
```

The DynamicComponentRegister is loaded by the JsComponentManager...

```
import PathManager from "../../SharedJs/path-manager";
import AppComponents from "./components/index.jsx";
import Dynamic from "../../SharedJs/components/dynamic-component-renderer";

export default class JsComponentManager {

    constructor(onLoader, pathManager) {
        this.loader = onLoader;
        this.pathManager = pathManager;
        this.select = {
            reactComponents: () => $(".js-react-component")
        }
    }

    bindComponents() {
        const paths = new PathManager();
        let $reactComponents = this.select.reactComponents()
        if ($reactComponents.length > 0) {
            this.loader.add(this.renderReactComponents, $reactComponents);
        }
    }

    renderReactComponents($elements) {
        $.makeArray($elements).forEach((el) => {
            let dynamicRenderer = new Dynamic(el, AppComponents);
            document.DynamicRenderers = document.DynamicRenderers || [];
            document.DynamicRenderers.push(dynamicRenderer);
            dynamicRenderer.render();
        });
    }
}
```

PathManager isn't doing anything in the current instance (it allows me to interrogate URLs and render components by URL but I'm not doing this at the moment). The 'onLoader' passed into the constructor queues up events against the onLoad event.

Comment: Isn't plain JavaScript object enough for this??`let componentRegistry = {dataList: DataList}` where `DataList` is your component and while accessing, `this.DynamicComponent=componentRegistry['dataList']`?

Comment: The purpose of the class is for cases where I don't know the type at runtime. It allows me to tie together server and client generated code elements. The component Registry isn't flat (example improved)

Comment: I suspect you don't want to hear this, but the best solution would be to just flatten the `componentRegistry` object.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how DynamicComponentRenderer is used?

Comment: That's not a viable solution really - I have numerous Index.jsx files with multiple components feeding into the registry - It would create massive duplication to do that with over 30 components. This is complicated further by the fact that I have components in a shared area between 2 front end apps that share and components  in the apps themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using eval just to resolve a path through some objects, you could instead use a function designed to traverse objects.

```
const traverseInternal = (object, keys, keyIndex) => {
  if (keyIndex >= keys.length) {
    return object;
  }

  return traverseInternal(object[keys[keyIndex]], keys, keyIndex + 1);
};

const traverse = (object, deepKey) => {
  return traverseInternal(object, deepKey.split('.'), 0);
};
```

Then replace

```
eval(`componentRegistry.${this.componentName}`);
```

with

```
traverse(componentRegistry, this.componentName);
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution. I'll give that a try.